# Address Info Syntax Error Node.js (Express)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, server

I am making a server using TypeScript that my angular app can connect to, but I get the following error when I try to run it: (PS I tried using destructuring with the AddressInfo, but Node.js or TS is not compatible yet with ES6 features)

```
const {address, port} = server.address() as AddressInfo;
                                             ^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:720:23)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:787:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:643:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:556:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:839:10)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:11
```

The code below:

```
const express = require('express');
const AddressInfo = require('AddressInfo');
const app = express();

app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('Hello from Express'));

app.get('/products', (req, res) => res.send('Got a request for products'));

app.get('/reviews', (req, res) => res.send('Got a request for reviews'));

const server = app.listen(8000, "localhost", () => {
    const {address, port} = server.address() as AddressInfo;
    console.log(`Listening on ${address}:${port}`);
});
```

Comment: I think the error should be multiple lines with the `^^` below the part of the line that causes the problem. Please [edit] your question to show the error message as you see it on your computer.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Alright! I made the edits...

Comment: I think you should just remove "as AddressInfo". This isn't valid JavaScript syntax.

Comment: If you are doing TypeScript instead of JavaScript, you should probably name your file `.ts` instead of `.js`. Not sure if this will solve the problem, but it is good practice.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Thank you so much! I removed "AddressInfo", and the code worked perfectly.... If you want to, you can submit that as the answer, and I will mark it as correct :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am making a server using TypeScript

More accurately, you are making a server using NodeJS. Node only natively supports JavaScript. The quick fix here is to remove `as AddressInfo` since this is TypeScript syntax, not JavaScript.

If you really want to use TypeScript instead of JavaScript, you need to rename your `.js` files to `.ts` and configure NodeJS to use TypeScript.

Answer (score 2):

The `as` key word is not vanilla JavaScript, it is TypeScript,also Node.js runs JavaScript, if you need to use TypeScript you can use the the node Typescript package it allows you to transpile `.ts` files into `.js` or use `babel`